# I am trying to write some VBA to help compare some data

Tags: vba, excel

Edit:

Based on the suggestion below I tried the following on sample data that should be pasting some data; it is not erroring, but it is not pasting data either:

```
Public Sub MakeCompareSheet()

Dim i As Long
Dim rCell As Range
Dim shBuild As Worksheet
Dim shComp As Worksheet

Set shBuild = Sheets("Builds")
Set shComp = Sheets("Build Compare")

For i = 2 To 8 Step 2 'cols B through H

    'loop through row 1 of the builds sheet
    For Each rCell In shBuild.Range("A1" & Columns.Count).Cells
        'if row 1 of builds = row 1, column i of comps
        'and if the cell below equals the cell below
        If rCell.Value = shComp.Cells(1, i).Value And rCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = shComp.Cells(2, i).Value Then

            'copy row 3 down 166 rows to the comps wheet
            rCell.Offset(2, 0).Resize(166, 1).Copy shComp.Cells(3, i)

            'Since we already found it, we don't need to look anymore
            Exit For
        End If
    Next rCell
Next i

End Sub
```

Edit #2:

When I go back to the original code it errors.  I suspect that is because the first thing it is searching for can be found in multiple cells.

For an example AAA### is in 6 cells in the Range. I am not sure why when I use Columns.Count it doesn't error but using a hard range it does.

Edit #3:

Well the above code does not work right and setting the range beyond ZZ1 breaks it as well.  I will have to let them know that as we approach ZZ we will need a new sheet to start over.

Edit #4:

```
Public Sub MakeCompareSheet()

Dim i As Long
Dim rCell As Range
Dim shBuild As Worksheet
Dim shComp As Worksheet

Set shBuild = Sheets("Builds")
Set shComp = Sheets("Build Compare")

If IsEmpty(shComp.Cells(1, 2)) = True Then
    MsgBox ("Please enter at least 1 build ID into Cell B1")
    Else
    If IsEmpty(shComp.Cells(2, 2)) = True Then
        MsgBox ("Please enter the phase for the build")
    End If
End If

    For i = 2 To 8 Step 2 'cols B through H

            'loop through row 1 of the builds sheet
            For Each rCell In shBuild.Range("A1").Resize(1, shBuild.Columns.Count).Cells
                'if row 1 of builds = row 1, column i of comps
                'and if the cell below equals the cell below
                If rCell.Value = shComp.Cells(1, i).Value And rCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = shComp.Cells(2, i).Value Then
                    If IsEmpty(rCell) Then GoTo 34 Else
                    'copy row 3 down 166 rows to the comps sheet
                    rCell.Offset(2, 0).Resize(166, 1).Copy shComp.Cells(3, i)

                    'Since we already found it, we don't need to look anymore
                Exit For
            End If
        Next rCell
34:     Next i

End Sub
```

that is the code as it stands now, working well.  Big thanks to Dick for all the help; I really appreciate it.

Comment: Need more info or photo to understand/help. Loops are tricky to architect if you're unfamiliar, best way is to just do trial and error.

Comment: If I could give a photo or upload of the data I would, but it is confidential information.

The builds sheet has columns of builds From I:CW (currently, though it can change and add columns) with buildname in row 1 and phasenum in row 2.  The rest of the data to look-up and copy are in rows 3 to 168.

the build compare sheet will have a blank cell in row 1 and row 2 for input of a buildname and phasenum.  I have been asked to take in 4 different buildnames and phasenum's to return data to compare.  so I need to lookup buildname1 and phasenum1 and paste the data, then loop to 2,3,4 and paste.

Comment: So the 4 buildnames and phasenums repeat in columns `I:CW`? Why did you only mention `column B, D, F, or H` in OP? Confused XD And what data size are you pulling from rows 3 to 168? Single cell? A range? Make up data or black it out for picture.

Comment: Here is my thinking: I need to find the buildname first, then shift down a row and see if it is the right phasenum, if not go to the next.  Also there will be multiple of the same buildname, but a different phase number per buildname. so AAA### can repeat multiple times, but phasenum will be 1 or 2 etc.

Comment: B,D,F, or H are the place where the person enters the buildname and phasenum they want to search for to compare.

The original data is on another sheet.

Comment: What data are you pulling? Is it something a pivot table or `sumif` can do? Edit: or just run with your thought. Trial and error is fine for loops. Come back with specific loop problem.

Comment: The problem is the way the data is setup a pivot table won't work.  The data is in rows and the buildnames are in columns. and there is a blank template column that is used on the main data sheet for adding new columns when they need to be added via vba.  I tried a pivot table already and it errors out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98010/discussion-between-user2867882-and-findwindow).

Comment: I can't chat. Try a shot at looping then ask a loop question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure putting those values in variables is the way to go.  In the below example, it reads each of the comps cells, finds that cell on builds, and copies the data over.

```
Public Sub MakeCompareSheet()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim shBuild As Worksheet
    Dim shComp As Worksheet

    Set shBuild = Sheets("Builds")
    Set shComp = Sheets("Build Compare")

    For i = 2 To 8 Step 2 'cols B through H

        'loop through row 1 of the builds sheet
        For Each rCell In shBuild.Range("A1:Z1").Cells

            'if row 1 of builds = row 1, column i of comps
            'and if the cell below equals the cell below
            If rCell.Value = shComp.Cells(1, i).Value And rCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = shComp.Cells(2, i).Value Then

                'copy row three down 166 rows to the comps wheet
                rCell.Offset(2, 0).Resize(166, 1).Copy shComp.Cells(3, i)

                'Since we already found it, we don't need to look anymore
                Exit For
            End If
        Next rCell
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this is way more simple than what I had originally thought.  I did make a modification I will post, but it is not pasting any data to the Build Compare page.  It does run with no errors though.

Comment: I was wrong, using your exact code does error with Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work; apparently setting the range beyond ZZ breaks it though.

Comment: `shBuild.Range("A1" & Columns.Count` does not do what you think it does. First, `Columns.Count` refers to the active sheet. You should use `shBuild.Columns.Count`, but really you shouldn't use that either. If there are, say, 16,384 columns in your worksheet, you will be looking at every cell in A116384 - which is one cell. Try `For Each rCell in shBuild.Range("A1").Resize(1,shBuild.Columns.Count).Cells` instead.

Comment: Yea, I figured out that it was not doing what I thought.  I will change to your other suggestion; thanks!